# Roslyn: Get definition of invoked method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing, roslyn

I need to find all the methods that are being invoked in a c# file.
just like the tool tip when the cursor is on a method in VS. or like go to definition.

I tried to use:

```
SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPosition
```

and it didn't find the symbol (returns `null` at `Result`):

I also tried:

```
 model.GetSymbolInfo(expression)
```

on the `InvocationExpressionSyntax`, and it returns `null` as well.

(I'll point out that the definitions of the invoked methods are in different classes, And I load all the relevant files to syntaxTrees and create a semantic model)

**EDIT**

As was suggested in the comments- I checked the `model.GetDiagnotics`, and it helped me to find the problem (problem with the code i loaded).

The methods I mentioned above work great.

Comment: I would start by calling GetDiagnotics on your Compilation and see if something is misconfigured. Maybe you don't have the right references?

Comment: Along with @KevinPilch-Bisson's advice, you might want to share the code you used to set up your SemanticModel, there's probably something wrong there.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson Thanks, The GetDiagnotics helped me to find the problem.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski It worked fine since then, but I encountered a problem today:  SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPosition finds me the wrong symbol... it finds a method with the same name but wrong input parameters... any idea?

Comment: Is this a case where there is multiple overloads being picked, but the code wasn't valid and thus we picked one via some heuristic?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Yes... thank you so much!!!